# Integer-based offset from index label

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas

In [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), is it possible to determine the index's label at a given integer offset from a known index label? For instance,

```
>>> df
    a  b
10  1  2
20  3  4
30  5  6
40  7  8
>>> df.index.offset(10, 3)
40
>>> df.index.offset(30, -1)
20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.Index.get_loc`

```
df.index[df.index.get_loc(10) + 3]

40
```

---

```
df.index[df.index.get_loc(30) - 1]

20
```